# Не открывается консоль БД по двойному клику

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains

Раньше **по двойному клику по файлу базы данных** в разделе **Project**, открывалась **консоль этой БД**. Но я разбираясь с FTP подключением, изменил тип файла **.db на формат SQL**, после этого консоль открываться перестала, и вместо консоли теперь открывается **текстовый документ в сбитой кодировке**. Всё ещё можно открыть консоль через **View -> Tool Windows -> Database**, но это не удобно. Подскажите, как можно это исправить?

Comment: Система? PyCharm полный или Community?

Comment: Я предполагаю, что вы не формат файла изменили, а расширение файла базы данных sqlite поменяли с `.db` на `.sql`. Как исправить - поменять расширение обратно.

Comment: @alex :D поздравляю!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

выделяем файл с списке файлов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нажимаем `File -> File properties -> Associate with file type...`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

откроется окно и выбираем первый чекпоинт. чтобы ассоциация была по контенту и заменяем имя файла на звездочку, чтобы создать маску под расширение. должно получиться `*.sqlite3`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого файл поменяет иконку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по дабл-клику будет открываться консоль.

Comment: Это помогло. Только file pattern надо задавать в виде маски, а не как имя файла. Например чтобы любые .db базы данных правильно работали, надо *.db